# Php array entry value and return key

Tags: php, arrays, session, key

Hi I have a `$_SESSION["product"]` array, `$_SESSION["product"]` `print_r` output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 152
            [name] => 0
            [total] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 343
            [name] => 0
            [total] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 799
            [name] => 0
            [total] => 7
        )

)
```

I want to output when I searched id and find main key for example; when I write 799 the output is 2 or

```
$_SESSION["product"][2]
```

Comment: So what have you tried.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested, but should work:

```
$search = 799; // id to search
foreach($_SESSION["product"] as $key => $array) // Look through session array
{
    if($array["id"] == $search) // Found your id
    {
        $output = $key; // Set id to variable
        break; // Exit loop
    }
}
echo $output; // Your output
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through and check the id. For example:

```
$search = 799;

foreach( $products as $key => $product ) {
    if( $product[ 'id' ] == $search ) {
       $item = $product;
       break;
    }
}

print_r( $product );
```

This is untested btw. This will print out what ever item matches the id. If you want just the key use this instead.

```
$item = $key;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple foreach loop will do that. When you hit the `id` you expect, return the key of the array record.

```
$search_for = 799;

foreach($_SESSION["product"] as $key => $data) {
    if($data['id'] == $search_for) {
        $result = $key;
        break;
    }
}

if($result) {
    echo 'Result is: ' . $result;
} else {
    echo 'No match';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getIndex($name, $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value) && $value['id'] == $name)
            return $key;
    }
    return null;
}
$array = Array(
    array(
        'id' => 152,
        'name' => 0,
        'total' => 3
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 152,
        'name' => 0,
        'total' => 3
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 799,
        'name' => 0,
        'total' => 7
    ),
);
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($array);
echo getIndex(799, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just make use of **`array_search()`**

```
$i=0;
foreach($arr as $val_arr)
{
    $key = array_search(799,$val_arr);
    if(!empty($key))
    {
        echo $i; //"prints" 2
    }
    $i++;

}
```